# Pyata module: Error connecting to localhost:3000: [Errno 10061]

Tags: python, puredata

I have successfully checked out pyata from the svn and configured the path variable. But now when I run example.py, as specified in the tutorial [here](https://code.google.com/p/pyata/wiki/How_To_Install), it gives me this error message:

```
initializing server.pd...
Error connecting to localhost:3000: [Errno 10061]  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 60, in <module>
    pd.init()
  File "C:\Users\Fredrik\Anaconda\pyata\src\Pd.py", line 37, in init
    self.clear()
  File "C:\Users\Fredrik\Anaconda\pyata\src\Pd.py", line 59, in clear
    self.c.send_pd(Box.canvas + "clear ; ")
  File "C:\Users\Fredrik\Anaconda\pyata\src\communication.py", line 125, in send_pd
    print "Error sending message %s : %s" % (message, err)
NameError: global name 'message' is not defined
```

The code generating the error:

```
#sending a command to pd
def send_pd(self, commands):
    try:
        self.snd_socket.send(commands)
        return True
    except error, err: 
        print "Error sending message %s : %s" % (message, err) 
        return False
```

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried disabling your firewall? Have you tried a different port?

Comment: please also post the source-code that is raising the error

Comment: I have tried disabling the firewall. I haven't tried a different port, the specified port should be the correct one. I wouldn't know which other one to try?

Comment: On a Linux system there should be the file /etc/services that contains all the ports and their registered services. No idea how that works on Windows though. Just try a few.